# Adding css when form submitted javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I want to add css to a class when my form is submitted because it take long time, but nothing change! here is my form

```
<form method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" name="submitAddProduct" class="btn btn-default button button-medium">
        <span>Garder<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

the `div` I want to change :

```
<div id="circlecontainer"></div>
```

and my script :

```
$('form.std').submit(function(e){
    $( "#circlecontainer" ).removeClass('whatever').addClass('whatever');
});
```

I want the button to be disabled too when the submit goes on?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to do an AJAX request? Or do you actually want a form submission, but want to disable the form submit button as the request is getting processed?

Comment: Add disabled attribute to the button on submit handler.

Comment: And to add any style to other element, add class when submit handler and remove it on submit success.

Comment: when i submit my form it take long time to submit cause there is many input , i want to disable the button for prevent user to send it again and display css

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitAddProduct" class="btn btn-default button button-medium">
        <span>Garder<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>
    </button>
</form>


$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    $("#circlecontainer").addClass('whatever');
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true).html('Please Wait...');
});
```

Comment: not working class not change and button still work ?

Answer (score 0):

Reason 1. you will need e.preventDefault(), otherwise submit the form will refresh the whole page
Reason 2. Since reason 1, You will need to use ajax to post the form data instead of using default form event, please refer to this question for how to set it up in your submit function [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#circlecontainer" ).removeClass('whatever')
    var frm = $('.std');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: //'your post url',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
               $("#circlecontainer").addClass('whatever');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add a listener to your button and change the class attribute

```
 var   divClassChanger=function()
     {
        var div=document.getElementByID("circlecontainer");
        div.setAttribute("class", "someotherclass");
        document.getElementById("yourBtnId").disabled = true;
      };

    document.getElementById("yourBtnId").addEventListener("click",divClassChanger);
```

you only need a id in you button

Answer (score -1):

You really need to consider using `Ajax request` as this will definitely solve your problem. As you have it

```
 <form method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <button type="submit" name="submitAddProduct" class="btn btn-default button button-medium">

            <span>Garder<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>

        </button>



</form>
```

**AJAX Request Script**

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this), url = $form.attr('action');//url could be your PHP script

    var posting = $.post(url, {$('yourinputs').val()});

    posting.done(function(data){
        $('.circlecontainer').removeClass('yourclass');
    });
});
```

This should work.